# Configuring Membership Provider with credentials setup in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I'm trying to implement Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC4 application and I've only one user who is going to get authenticated to do some admin activities.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="2880" loginUrl="~/Admin/Login" slidingExpiration="true">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="user" password="password"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

When I try to use the `FormsAuthentication.ValidateUser` method I get an obsolete warning and I'm supposed to use now `Membership` class.

My question is how I can configure membership provider in web.config to use the credentials setup in the web.config? What provider I should specify in the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in membership provider for the mechanism of storing the credentials in the web.config as you describe.  You could write your own to invoke the [FormsAuthentication.Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx) method or call this from your own custom login control's code-behind.